# Hibernate maven web project no suitable dirver found MYSQL

Tags: hibernate, maven, web-applications, hibernate-mapping, mysql-connector

I am new to hibernate learning. When I did simple maven project everything worked perfectly i.e. connecting to mysql database. Now,when I am building a maven web project and using the same configuration ie. hibernate.cfg.xml I am getting an error saying "Not a suitable error driver found". I did check other posts for the same error but did not find anything wrongs so far as url or library is concerned. Attched below is the error and required files.

Error:

```
May 11, 2023 11:32:02 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhiber
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService.....
```

I referred the threads for similar problems and did not find anything wrong as mentioned solutions were correct for my configuration. But did not find anything specific to maven webpp related to hibernate database issue.

I am using Eclipse IDE(Neon),MYSQLP DB version 8. There is no lib folder that is usually there with normal web project where I could paste mysql lib connector jar. But I am not sure if anything is wrong with structure itself.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.todo</groupId>
  <artifactId>NoteTaker</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>NoteTaker Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>NoteTaker</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver.class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhiber</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.entities.Note"/>    
        
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: You have to add the driver jar as a dependecy in maven

Comment: it has been added. Forgot to mention other details. I have added now.

Comment: I was able to solve it by chaning connection.driver.class to connection.driver_class.